# Integral Transform of exponential function over the positive axes

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, fourier-analysis

How do you integrate $\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{i \omega x}\ \mathrm dx$?

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica 11.2.0.0  correctly performs

```
Integrate[Exp[I*ω*x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[I/ω, Im[ω] > 0]

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform). Since [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform) integrates from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the following will give you the answer *(updated per @J.M. comment)*:

```
res = FourierTransform[Sqrt[2 Pi] HeavisideTheta[x], x, ω]
```

> I/ω + π DiracDelta[ω]

Let's check if the inverse reproduces the desired theta function:

```
InverseFourierTransform[res, ω, x]
```

> Sqrt[π/2] (1 + Sign[x])

Comment: `FourierTransform[Sqrt[2 π] HeavisideTheta[x], x, ω]` ought to work, too.

Comment: @J.M. That's what I tried first, but it didn't work for some reason. Maybe lingering definitions.